# Continuity of the mapping of a lattice in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ onto the length of the shortest vector

Tags: matrices, integer-lattices

I have the following problem:

> Let $X_{d}:=\{\mathbb{Z}^{d}g;g\in\operatorname{SL}_{d}(\mathbb{R})\}$ and define $\lambda:X_{d}\to(0,\infty)$ by: $$ \lambda(\Lambda):=\min\left\{r>0;\Lambda\cap \overline{B_{r}^{\mathbb{R^{d}}}(0)}\neq\emptyset\right\}\quad\forall\Lambda\in X_{d}$$ Let $g\in\operatorname{SL}_{d}(\mathbb{R})$ and $(h_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\operatorname{SL}_{d}(\mathbb{R})^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that $h_{n}\to1$ $(\in\operatorname{SL}_{d}(\mathbb{R}))$. Then $$\lambda(\mathbb{Z}^{d}gh_{n})\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}\lambda(\mathbb{Z}^{d}g)$$

(In the entire discussion think of vectors as $1\times d$ matrices.)

$\lambda$ is well-defined thanks to Minkowski's first theorem. It is clear that $\lim\sup\lambda(\mathbb{Z}^{d}gh_{n})\leq\lambda(\mathbb{Z}^{d}g)$. So what I wanted to show was $\lim\inf\lambda(\mathbb{Z}^{d}gh_{n})>\lambda(\mathbb{Z}^{d}g)-\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$.

What I tried was the following: assuming otherwise, we can without loss of generality (switching to a subsequence) assume that there is a sequence $(v_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in(\mathbb{Z}^{d})^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that:
$$\lVert v_{n}gh_{n}\rVert< \lambda(\mathbb{Z}^{d}g)-\frac{\epsilon}{2}\leq\lVert v_{n}g\rVert-\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$
Now I wanted to get the contradiction out of this. The problem was that the $v_{n}$ depended on $n\in\mathbb{N}$, so this did not directly yield the desired contradiction as they could diverge in norm to $\infty$.

I arrived at the point where I thought there was no way around it but trying to show that the $v_{n}$ stabilize. So I guessed the following:

> Let $(h_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\operatorname{SL}_{d}(\mathbb{R})^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that $h_{n}\to 1$, $(v_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\mathbb{R}^{d}$ an $M>0$ such that $\lVert v_{n}h_{n}\rVert\leq M$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $(h_{n})_{\mathbb{N}}$ has compact closure.

I did not manage to show that. Can you help me on how to prove this or can you tell me whether the guess is wrong (which would astonish me)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have decided to prove the following:

> Let $K\subseteq\operatorname{SL}_{d}(\mathbb{R})$ compact and $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{d}$. If $\sup_{a\in A,k\in K}\lVert ak \rVert<\infty$, then $A$ is bounded.

It turns out that after having arranged the things in my head a bit, the proof seems rather easy. Clearly $\phi:\mathbb{R}^{d}\times \operatorname{SL}_{d}(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}^{d}$ given by $(v,g)\mapsto vg$ is continuous and $K^{-1}=\{k^{-1};k\in K\}$ is compact. As $\sup_{a\in A,k\in K}\lVert ak \rVert<\infty$, $\overline{AK}:=\overline{\{ak;a\in A, k\in K\}}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{d}$ is compact and thus $\phi(\overline{AK}\times K^{-1})$ has compact image and thus is bounded. As $A\subseteq\phi(\overline{AK}\times K^{-1})$, $A$ is bounded.

Do you agree that this solves my problem?